# npm search result sort anomaly

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm looking for a node.js stopwatch package, so I tried what seemed to be an obvious enough search:

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=stopwatch&page=1&ranking=popularity

However, that's giving me as the first result a package called `stopwatch` which has only 33 downloads in the last month, and as the second result a package called `nanotimer` which has 19015 downloads in the last month, so it's not presenting descending order of popularity as specified.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ljharb on freenode #Node.js for the answer: apparently the exact match for your search term always shows up first.